# Building a trivial program with dpkg-buildflags

Tags: c, gcc, debian

I'm trying to build a very simple C program for inclusion into a .deb package. The bulk of the project is in Python. When this program is included into a .deb package, `lintian` gives me the `hardening-no-fortify-functions` warning.

On further reading, it appears that Debian expects you to include certain flags while building C programs, and that these flags can be retrieved using `dpkg-buildflags --get CFLAGS`.

My initial build flags looked like this:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -o somefile somefile.c
```

Now, I'm building with

```
CFLAGS=`dpkg-buildflags --get CFLAGS`
gcc $CFLAGS -o somefile somefile.c
```

However, I continue to get the `hardening-no-fortify-functions` warning. What am I doing wrong here? Is this now a false positive? Can I just add an override and forget about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilities of which the third seems most likely, but I've mentioned 1 and 2 in case they are causing you problems too:

1. `dpkg-buildflags --get CFLAGS` is returning the wrong thing. On my system it returns:

   `-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security`

   If you just execute it from the command line, what do you get?
2. Your value of `CFLAGS` is not being passed to `gcc`. I assume you are using a `Makefile` here; are those two statements actually adjacent? Do you not want `CFLAGS =` (with a space) if so? Or are you setting `CFLAGS` at the command line in which case you should know the debian build tool stuff strips the environment of most things that don't start `DEB_`, so you will need to set `CFLAGS` inside whatever builds the package.
3. The `CFLAGS` aren't sufficient to eliminate the hardening error. Let's have a look at the lintian error: http://lintian.debian.org/tags/hardening-no-fortify-functions.html and note it says 'Certainty: wild guess'. That does not inspire confidence that it is correct. However, I suspect the actual problem is this: you are not bringing in `LDFLAGS`. Try:

   `$ dpkg-buildflags --get LDFLAGS`

   `-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro`

You'll need those on your linker line.

This approach would seem to work (i.e. at least compile):

```
gcc `dpkg-buildflags --get CFLAGS` `dpkg-buildflags --get LDFLAGS` main.c -o main
```

Comment: That did it. `LDFLAGS` was missing, causing that error to continue being raised.